# jQuery simultaneous animation on elements

Tags: jquery, animation

I have 2 elements with class `wave-bar`. (Actually more but for the sake of the example let's say 2)

The code below changes the height of the elements to random values (to create a waveform (think audio player) effect).

The code currently changes the height 10000 times for the first element and when that is finished it goes on and changes the second element's height.

However I would like both elements to get random heights at the same time. So that the animation  of the second element doesn't wait for the first one to finish.

```
  $('.wave-bar').each(function() {

    var bar = $(this);

    for (var i=0;i<=10000;i++) {
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        var rand_no = Math.floor(Math.random()*19);

        bar.height(rand_no);
        bar.css('margin-top', (18-rand_no)+'px');
      }, 500);
    }
 });
```

How to set this up?

Comment: Why not use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

Comment: It sucks!!!!!! Any ideas as to how to run it 10k times without messing up my pc? :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd create a simple jQuery plugin and apply it to each element something like this:

```
$.fn.pulseRandom = function () {
    var repulse = function ( $elem ) {
        var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 ),
            time = Math.floor( Math.random() * 250 ) + 250;

        $elem.animate({ height: rand, 'margin-top': 100 - rand }, time - 1);

        setTimeout(function(){ repulse( $elem ); }, time);
    };

    repulse( this );
};

$('.wave-bar').each(function(i,ele){
    $(ele).pulseRandom();
});
```

I also randomized the timing a bit to make it look a little more organic.

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Bdvz/)

Answer (score 1):

Adding another setTimeout. Like this:

```
$('.wave-bar').each(function() {

    var bar = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){  //Added this setTimeout
      for (var i=0;i<=10000;i++) {
         window.setTimeout(function() {
           var rand_no = Math.floor(Math.random()*19);

           bar.height(rand_no);
           bar.css('margin-top', (18-rand_no)+'px');
         }, 500);
       }
    },0);

 });
```

This will create separate "threads" for each element, so they will animate at the same time.

Cheers

PS:I you're using jquery, you should check the `.animate()` method, it's very cool and easy to use.

Comment: Above didn't work. Although using your suggestion (animate) does. So I replaced the timeout function with animate function. Thanks for that. But the reason I didn't use animate in the first place was because I though it would have an impact on the performance. And what do you know it is running now, but it totally eats both my CPU and my mem :P Any ideas how to improve it?